# Textfield result into a hyperlink

Tags: php, html, hyperlink, textfield

I have made this form where you write you name, lastname, phone and email.
With HTML and PHP.

```
name: "textfield here"
lastname: "textfield here"
phone: "textfield here"
email: "textfield here"
```

My PHP code:

```
 echo "<H1>Hello " .$_POST['name']. " " .$_POST['surname']; 

 echo "I'm calling you at " .$_POST['telephone']. " or email you at ".$_POST['email'];
```

How do I make the result of `email` come out as a hyperlink?

Comment: You just want to make the email address a link?

Comment: -1 Do some research on your own before asking.

Comment: I did! But i couldn't find a thing! :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a link use an `<a>` tag and for an email link you can set the `href` to `mailto:xyz`.

[Mailto reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto).

Also consider researching XSS because your code is vulnerable. Note the use below of `htmlentities()` to prevent XSS.

```
echo "<h1>Hello " .htmlentities($_POST['name']). " " .htmlentities($_POST['surname']) . "</h1>"; 

echo "<p>I'm calling you at " .htmlentities($_POST['telephone']). " or email you at <a href=\"mailto:" . htmlentities($_POST['email']) . "\">".htmlentities($_POST['email']) . "</a></p>";
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked! But could you explain to me what htmlentities is?

Comment: In this example I used `htmlentities()` to prevent XSS which is a common web vulnerability. See php.net/htmlentnties also consider marking this answer as accepted (by clicking the tick) if it answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "I'm calling you at " .$_POST['telephone']. " or email you at <a href=\"mailto:{$_POST['email']}\">{$_POST['email']}</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

A mailto?

Not that I like it at all (You'll find it hard to find anybody who does)...

```
echo "I'm calling you at " .$_POST['telephone']. " or email you at <a href='mailto:".$_POST['email']."'>".$_POST['email']."</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this one:

```
    echo "I'm calling you at " .$_POST['telephone']. " or email you at 
    <a href=\"mailto:".$_POST['email'].">" $_POST['email']."</a>";
```

Comment: It says there's a syntax error.